# How to create pages output as flat hierarchy

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a Gatsby website (v3.10.2) where I'm creating pages using the createPage API.

Here is my code in `create-pages.ts` for reference:

```
function createPages({ actions: { createPage } }) {
    const pagesList = [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: LandingTemplate,
            context: {},
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            component: AboutUsTemplate,
            context: {},
        },
    ]

    // 404 — Always last
    pagesList.push({
        path: '/404.html',
        matchPath: '/*',
        component: NotFoundTemplate,
        context: {},
    });

    for (const page of pageList) {
       createPage(page);
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting from my build looks like this:

```
public
 -- index.html
 -- about
    -- index.html
```

The output I'm looking to achieve is something like:

```
public
 -- index.html
 -- about.html
```

That is, I want to have all pages flat in the build folder, with their name, instead of having a folder for each page with the index file.

Is this possible using Gatsby somehow?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to achieve this. Gatsby has not implemented this feature and it doesn't seem to be in the roadmap according to what's extracted in the [Configurable output folder](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/1878) GitHub discussion.

`/public` it's [automatically generated](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-project-structure/) and there aren't many ways besides path prefixing of customizing it, at least at 31th of October of 2021.